# Change color of a CSS when mouse hover an TD

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I'm developing an site with a large table (18 row x 11 columns). To make it easier for who is looking that table, I made it hover an different color for the TR with that:

```
.responsive tr:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But I want to make the same with the column. But if I use `.responsive td:hover {background-color: blue;}`, it just hovers the single TD, not the entire column. At least, every TD has the class `col1`, `col2`, etc.

How is it possible to change a CSS property when hovering the TD. If this is possible, I can change the `background-color` from class `col1` when I hover the `col1` TD.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of column in HTML or CSS.

You must use javascript to do that.

Here's a solution using jQuery :

```
var clean = function(){
   $('td').removeClass('colHover');
}
$('td').hover(
    function() {
       clean();
       $('td:nth-child('+($(this).index()+1)+')').addClass('colHover');
    }, clean
);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/KCDzX/)

---

Now, mainly for fun, if you want to handle colspan, you could do that :

```
var clean = function(){
   $('td').removeClass('colHover');
}
$('td').hover(
    function() {
       clean();
       var col = 0;
      $(this).prevAll().each(function(){col += parseInt($(this).attr('colspan')||'1')});
      $('tr').each(function(){
        var c = 0, done = false;
        $('td',this).each(function(){
          if (c>col && !done) {
            $(this).prev().addClass('colHover');
            done = true;
          }
          c += parseInt($(this).attr('colspan')||'1');
        });
        if (!done) $(this).find('td:last-child').addClass('colHover');
      });
    }, clean
);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/7VWjk/)

Comment: Note that supporting `colspan` might be a bit difficult so this solution does not attempt to

Comment: @JanDvorak The main problem in supporting colspan is to decide what's the goal.

Comment: I suggest: Highlight all cells that overlap any column that overlaps the cell that is hovered.

Comment: That's a good approach, but I would instead define a class for each 'column' and change the css class instead of asking JQuery to iterate through a selection, using the .css method - like [$('.classname').css('font-size','12px');], for example.

Comment: @OnoSendai I suggest a third approach: use classes `.col1, .col2...` to attach the `.colHover` class. Then the colspans are easy to target once computed

Comment: @JanDvorak I made a version handling colspan. But looking at the question it's probably not needed.

Comment: @dystroy nice one :-) , even if you have a different idea of what should be highlighted

Comment: Really thanks guy :) Saved my day. I just don't understand the code yet because never study those scripts, but it work like a charm :)

Comment: If you can borrow 1 more minute of your lives, what exactly this line make?

`$('td:nth-child('+($(this).index()+1)+')').addClass('colHover');`

Comment: It adds the class `colHover` to all `td` whose index in their parent element (the row) is the index of `this` (which is the hovered `td`). The +1 is due to the fact [this specific selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) is 1 based.